# Where to best use setRequestedOrientation inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I want to use `setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` inside a class that extends `Fragmnet`, where it should be best used? inside `onCreateView()`, `onActivityCreated` or `onCreate()`? and how? because when I tried to use it, eclipse underline it with red squiggle.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should precede

`setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` with `getActivity()` so you can get instance of the current activity your `Fragment` is associated with.

And, I think you could use it inside `onCreateView()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use it inside of onCreateView() by calling your activity like thi

```
Activity a = getActivity();
    if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

A note here is that it changes your activites orientation when this fragment is called.  You cannot change the orientation of a fragment, but you can change the orientation of the activity from a fragment.